# What is the GPars default pool size?

Tags: groovy, concurrency, gpars

I thought this would have been an easy thing to find but I've failed.

If I use GPars in my Groovy application and I don't specify a pool size how many threads will be created? Is there a default pool size without setting one?

```
// How many threads will be created? What is the default pool size?
GParsExecutorsPool.withPool {
    // do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is (by default) set to

```
private static int defaultPoolSize() {
  return Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1;
}
```

You can alter this (I believe) by setting a System property called `gpars.poolsize` to a valid Integer

Comment: Why is it "availableProcessors" plus one? I'd expect it to be minus one, to  leave one available for other systems? (unless of course you only have one to begin with!)

Answer (score 8):

As many as you have CPU units plus one, as shown by the `PoolUtils` class [source](https://github.com/vaclav/GPars/blob/master/src/main/groovy/groovyx/gpars/util/PoolUtils.java), or from a system property

`retrieveDefaultPoolSize()` is called once as a final static variable by the GParsPool class when it's initialized

Comment: Thanks, upvoted you for the source link. But had to give tim_yates the answer for being first :-)